# Actions on Google - Unable to create a valid release for DialogFlow - Known Issue?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have been trying to create a release on Actions for Google for my Dialogflow app. While I create an release on Action for Google in Alpha, Beta or in Production, and test the newly created version in the simulator, it always results in

```
MalformedResponse: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse 
because of empty speech response
```

I had contacted support for DialogFlow and they had requested for the project exported as zip for their review, then screenshots, then screencast, then silent for a while now. When I was trying to search for solution, I bumped into this link - https://developers.google.com/actions/support/known-issues that suggests a known issue creating a release in Actions for Google

Screenshot at [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFSJb.jpg ]

Here is the error recorded in the log

```
{
 insertId:  "1qftsp5g2pbrnfh"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/newagent-c9442/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-05-15T14:13:43.071392711Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "MalformedResponse: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response"  
 timestamp:  "2019-05-15T14:13:43.059656072Z"  
 trace:  "projects/886146653413/traces/ABwppHEE7jwH_FaSXqLBKMDjat2IGSewYttEE1U3Xe9IyBhzLy68MyC6GHCdV9VDBoVQ9NF9qgv-xe5XEgY"  
}
```

Anyone else have encountered this issue or any information relating to creating a release on Actions for Google. I'm sure I am not the only one but without creating a release, no actions/skills can be added to Google Assistant as well. So thought to check with the community. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, do you have a git repo? It would be easier to check if there were no errors on your side first. In my case, everything works fine deployment-wise.

Comment: Well, its  a standard dialogflow welcome intent with some small talk and NO webhook. I have verified that it is functional using test harness within dialogflow as well as through different integrations such as Facebook Messenger and Telegram. Even the Actions For Google simulator works with DRAFT version.ONLY when a release is created is when this issue surfaces.  GitHub repo for the agent is at https://github.com/thinkcodellc/voicein-dialogflow